# Get a textbox value inside a div in jquery php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i need to get the user id in the hidden field for each users in the click of the div or the a tag.

```
<?php 
foreach($user as $users)
{?>
<div class="user1">
<a class='inline' href="#inline_content" id="new2" >
<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/profile/<?php 
echo  $users['p_user_photo'];?>" /></a>
<input type="hidden" class="user_id" value="<?php echo $users['p_user_id'];?>"/>
<div class="user1_detail"><?php echo $users['p_user_name'];?>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('.user1').click(function(){
var user=('.user_id').val();
});
});
</script>
```

i need to get the user id in the hidden field for each users in the click of the div or the a tag.

Comment: How is your `$user` array defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get element with class `user_id` in current div having class `user1`

```
$(function(){
  $('.user1').click(function(){
     var user= $(this).find('.user_id').val();
  });
});
```

You can also pass current object as a *context* in the selector using [jQuery( selector [, context ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1)

```
$(function(){
     $('.user1').click(function(){
       var user=('.user_id', this).val();
     });
});
```

Comment: You are welcome and welcome to SO, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
   $('.user1').click(function(){
      var user = $(this).find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
      console.log("The user is: "+user);
   });
});
```

What we are doing here is [finding](http://api.jquery.com/find/) the hidden input inside the div that was clicked and fetching its value. `$(this)` here refers to the div that was clicked.

The problem in your code was:

- You were missing the `$` sign
- You would have fetched the values of all hidden inputs once you had
  put the `$` sign.